# Nginx Cache first browser request always Miss

Tags: nginx, caching, browser-cache, nginx-reverse-proxy

```
    location /api/framework {
      add_header Cache-Control "no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0";
      proxy_cache framework_cache;
      proxy_cache_use_stale updating;
      proxy_cache_lock on;
      proxy_cache_valid any 3600s;
      proxy_ignore_headers X-Accel-Expires Expires Cache-Control;
      add_header X-Proxy-Cache    $upstream_cache_status;

      rewrite ^/api/(.*) /$1 break;
      client_max_body_size 60M;
      proxy_set_header Connection "";
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
      proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For   $remote_addr;
      proxy_connect_timeout 5;
      proxy_send_timeout 60;
      proxy_read_timeout 70;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_pass http://kong;
  }
```

I've enabled caching for my backend. But **first request from browser** always shows `Miss` after that my requests are HIT. Is there anything I'm missing; even after I populated the cache using curl command

```
proxy_cache_path /tmp/framework_cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=framework_cache:5m max_size=700m inactive=60m use_temp_path=off;
```

Above is my cache config

Thank you.

Comment: The first request always miss from cache. Are you talking about a new browser request the same and missing from cache? Can you share some logs from nginx?

Comment: Hi @DilsonRainov Yeah, a new browser request always a miss. which log are you talking about? Usual Nginx logs, for the first request always give upstream time and response time. For the second time upstream is 0.00

Comment: May you explain how is the request? There's cookie envolved or it's a simple GET? Why are you setting the "no-cache" and "max-age=0" parameters?

Comment: Those options I got from a blog. Yeah we're setting cookie. But even when I change the proxy_cache_key to $request_uri the bahaviour is same.